# play framework - how to parse json array with possible null values

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6, play-json

I have following case class

`case class DataResponse(results: Iterable[Array[Option[String]]], exceptionMessage: Option[String])`

I can't seem to be able to write Reads for this class mainly because of type of `results`. If I try without option. i.e. `Iterable[Array[String]]` it works but then it blows up when json string has null values.

`implicit val DataReads2 = (
(JsPath \ “results”).read[Iterable[Array[Option[String]]]] and //compile error
(JsPath \ “exceptionMessage”).readNullable[String]
)(DataResponse.apply _)`

compile error:

`No Json deserializer found for type Iterable[Array[Option[String]]]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.`

If I try to implement implicit Reads for that I get:

`implicit val itrOptReads = Json.reads[Iterable[Array[Option[String]]]]`

`No apply function found for scala.collection.Iterable`

basically, I can't seem to find a simpler way to handle unmarsheling json to  `Iterable[Array[Option[String]]]` . there should be one.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a `CustomIterableFormat` in this case. Here's the example:

```
object CustomIterableFormat extends Reads[Iterable[Array[Option[String]]]] with Writes[Iterable[Array[Option[String]]]] {
  implicit val optionalStringArrayFormat = CustomArrayFormat
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Iterable[Array[Option[String]]]] = {
    Try(json.as[Iterable[JsValue]].map { someJson =>
      someJson.as[Array[Option[String]]]
    }).map(JsSuccess(_)).getOrElse(JsError(s"invalid sequence: $json"))
  }

  override def writes(o: Iterable[Array[Option[String]]]): JsValue = {
    Json.toJson(o)
  }
}

object CustomArrayFormat extends Reads[Array[Option[String]]] with Writes[Array[Option[String]]] {
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Array[Option[String]]] = {
    Try(json.as[Array[JsValue]].map {
      case JsNull          => None
      case JsString(value) => Some(value)
    }).map(JsSuccess(_)).getOrElse(JsError(s"invalid sequence: $json"))
  }

  override def writes(o: Array[Option[String]]): JsValue = {
    Json.toJson(o)
  }
}
```

And then just import the CustomIterableFormat in your companion object:

```
case class DataResponse(results: Iterable[Array[Option[String]]], exceptionMessage: Option[String])

object DataResponse {
  implicit val resultsFormat = CustomIterableFormat

  implicit val DataReads2 = (
    (JsPath \ "results").read[Iterable[Array[Option[String]]]] and
      (JsPath \ "exceptionMessage").readNullable[String]
  )(DataResponse.apply _)

}
```

Here's a simple working example:

```
object TestDataResponseParsing {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val jsonStr = """{"results":[[null,"testing"]],"exceptionMessage":null}"""
    val parsedFromJson = Json.parse(jsonStr).as[DataResponse]
    println(parsedFromJson)
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the complete solution! but there's gotta be simpler solution. This is very normal example of Json input. Most JSON library would handle that off the shelf. Do you recommend any other alternative json libe for scala?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53665440/6335075 - a more elegant solution using one of the popular JSON parsing library in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

[Circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/) is one of the most popular JSON parsing library in Scala

Here's a more elegant solution using [Circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/).

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser

case class DataResponse(results: Iterable[Array[Option[String]]], exceptionMessage: Option[String])

object DataResponseParsing extends App {

  val jsonStr = """{
                  "results" : [
                      [
                        null,
                        "bar-1"
                      ],
                      [
                         "foo-2",
                         "bar-2"
                       ]
                    ],
                    "exceptionMessage" : null
                  }""".stripMargin

  val result = parser.decode[DataResponse](jsonStr)

  val dataResponse = result match {
    case Right(value) => value
    case Left(error) => throw error
  }
  println(dataResponse)
}
```

[Circe's automatic derivation](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/auto-derivation.html) is very well versed and it automatically encode/decode almost all types of Scala objects. So we don't need to define implicit anywhere. Just import `io.circe.generic.auto._` in your Scala class and that's it.

[Here's](https://medium.com/@djoepramono/how-to-parse-json-in-scala-c024cb44f66b) a good reference blog for parsing JSON using [Circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/)

Hope this helps!!